# WordPress Multiple loop - first loop shows on top of every post page

Tags: wordpress, loops

i got a little problem with my wordpress loop. 
I created 2 loops in the front-page, the first loop is just only 1 post from 'featured' category (kind like the sticky post) . the second loop just the normal loop (exclude that 1 post from 'featured' category).

However, the problem is that my first loop(that 1 post from featured category) always display on top of each page, e.g homepage, 2nd page of post, 3rd page of post.

Below are my code, don't know what went wrong. help appreciated.

```
<?php do_action( 'responsive_mobile_blog_title' ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/loop-header' ); ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=featured&posts_per_page=1' );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php responsive_mobile_paging_nav(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a template with 2 loops, so of course these 2 loops will continue to show wherever this template is used...

When you say "2nd page of post" etc, do you mean 2, 3, 4 etc pages of pagination on the front page?

If you want to display your first loop on page 1 only, then you would need to add in an extra if statement around your first loop, another example can be found here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31065/how-to-determine-if-im-on-the-first-page-of-pagination

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. i wrap the first loop in the if (!is_paged()), it works great now. first loop now only displays in the first page,  not in 2, 3, 4 pages of pagination. previously i modified the multiple loop code directly from the wordpress Codex example, there is no if (!is_paged()), so i never thought about it. just start to learn modifying wordpress. thanks you so much.

Comment: No problem, if my post helped you, please mark it as the correct answer :)